# Android Lollipop setAdapter slow

Tags: android, eclipse, android-5.0-lollipop, simplecursoradapter

I have a large query, that I run like:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(SQL, null);
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listItens);
String[] fromFields = new String[] {fields...};
int[] toView = new int[] {ids...};
BaseAdapter adapter = new AdaptaListaItem(ItemList.this,R.layout.layout_item,c,toView);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the `AdaptaListaItem` extends `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

The problem:
On devices running Lollipop, when debug gets to `setAdapter`, that takes several seconds to render (like 40 seconds!).

It's only on Lollipop, any other version that doesn't happen.

What I can do?

ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstitemlista"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtItemListaResultados"
    android:divider="#cccccc"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    />
```

Comment: I forgot to say... the result is about 50 registers... not more than that!

Comment: Post XML layout file with `R.id.listItens`

Comment: post your custom SimpleCursorAdapter, why do you want to extend it anyway?